# Using Motor with uMongo :: Always Getting None

Tags: python-3.7, umongo

I'm trying to figure out how to use uMongo with Monitor and I am having a problem. I can't get the uMongo document object to return anything other than None and I am sure it's something obvious I just keep overlooking. If anyone has any suggestions or can see something I don't please let me know.

The connection string was sanitized, it's not really like this in my code.

Here is the test file I'm using:

```
import asyncio, pprint
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from umongo import Document, Instance, fields

# plain motor connection
client = AsyncIOMotorClient('mongodb+srv://user:password@atlas.azure.mongodb.net')
db = client.my_database

# umongo motor connection
instance = Instance(db)

# umongo document object
@instance.register
class User(Document):
    nickname = fields.StringField()
    gender = fields.StringField()

    class Meta:
        collection = db.test


# plain motor query function
async def plain_motor_find_one():
    document = await db.test.find_one({'nickname': 'rook'})  # this works
    pprint.pprint(document)


# umongo motor query function
async def umongo_motor_find_one():
    document = await User.find_one({'nickname': 'rook'})  # this does not and returns None
    pprint(document)

# grab event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# make our calls
loop.run_until_complete(plain_motor_find_one())
loop.run_until_complete(umongo_motor_find_one())
```

And here is what the object in my database.test collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b9c205ac19a8a91658f17"),
    "nickname" : "rook",
    "gender" : "male"
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use Motor and asynchronous, follow this code:

```
import asyncio

from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient

from umongo import Document, fields
from umongo.frameworks import MotorAsyncIOInstance

client = AsyncIOMotorClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = client.shop
instance = MotorAsyncIOInstance(db)


@instance.register
class User(Document):
    name = fields.StringField()

    class Meta:
        collection = db.user


async def plain_motor_find_one():
    document = await User.find_one({'foo': 'bar'}) # now all methods are awaitable
    print(document)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(plain_motor_find_one())
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It returns `None` always anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part:

```py
# umongo motor connection
instance = Instance(db)
```

`umongo.Instace` is an abstract class and it's used to be implemented, not to be used directly.
You should use `PymongoInstance`, `MotorAsyncIOInstance` which are the implementation of `Instance` class for `Pymongo` and `Motor` drivers, respectively.

Here you should use `MotorAsyncIOInstance` when you want to use `Motor` driver.

Instead of the above snippet, use the below snippet and it'll do the job.

```py
from umongo.frameworks import MotorAsyncIOInstance
instance = MotorAsyncIOInstance(db)
```